How can I run the Wikipedia Module Yesno.lua from the lua cli?
Wikipedia has lua modules. One of them is the Yesno module.
Its Yesno.lua file has these contents.
return function (val, default)
        -- If your wiki uses non-ascii characters for any of "yes", "no", etc., you
        -- should replace "val:lower()" with "mw.ustring.lower(val)" in the
        -- following line.
        val = type(val) == 'string' and val:lower() or val
        if val == nil then
                return nil
        elseif val == true 
                or val == 'yes'
                or val == 'y'
                or val == 'true'
                or val == 't'
                or val == 'on'
                or tonumber(val) == 1
        then
                return true
        elseif val == false
                or val == 'no'
                or val == 'n'
                or val == 'false'
                or val == 'f'
                or val == 'off'
                or tonumber(val) == 0
        then
                return false
        else
                return default
        end

From the lua cli prompt, I would like to load that function definition and execute it.

As long as the module is in your LUA_PATH (see The require function in Programming in Lua), you can just require it and execute the function:
local yes_no = require("yesno")
print(yes_no("y")) -- should print true

It all comes down to where you're putting the module and how you intend to use it.
If it's available on LuaRocks (though I couldn't find it there), you can just install it globally.
You may also just copy-paste the code into any directory that's part of your LUA_PATH (or you can add a custom directory to your LUA_PATH), if you're only planning on using it in your CLI.
If you need the module in a bigger project and it isn't available on LuaRocks, you can just put it somewhere in your project (while observing licensing conditions, if any, of course).
